# Adobe Air/Actionscript/Flex for IOS IPhone 4 Camera Rotated 90 degrees

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript, air, camera

Very strange, not sure if others have experienced this...
Exporting with Flash CS5.5 to iOS devices...
Basically if you use getCamera() and get an IPhone 4's front facing camera, when you export SWF inside the IDE (and uses your laptops camera for testing), output seems fine. However, once exported and put onto IPhone the video from the front facing camera is **rotated 90 degrees** It's size is also messed up too and not the same as in the IDE sometimes.

This may also occur with IPad too .. Not sure though as I don't have one to test.

This appears to me like an Adobe bug but wanted to see if others have experienced this problem?

I'm writing an app that is trying to parse QR codes and it's extremely annoying to debug this issue! Certainly this wouldn't of slipped by Adobe's team when they tested their APIs?

Comment: shouldn't the "Adobe Air" and "iOS" tags combine like mater and antimatter and implode this question leaving only pure energy floating about the internet?

Comment: @bshirley not sure what you're getting at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just updated to Ios5  Beta5 this morning on my iPad2 and this issue seems to be resolved.  The stage now does not rotate coming out of the camera API.

Answer (score 0):

Have same issue
quick fix :  when you access your camera and need to show it in stage you certainly be using "flash.media.Video" object, so just rotate the Video instance to fix it.